# return result from function in symfony as global in twig templates

Tags: symfony, twig, global

I have a function that returns the number of items in the cart. How it is possible to display this number in every  page of the website? I need to show its value in a twig file that is being loaded in all pages of the site...

This is the function I d like to use:

```
public function getCartCount(){

  $session = new Session();

  $session_user =  $session->get('temp_session_user');

  $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();  

  $details = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:RechargeLogs')->findBy(array(

        'sessionVal'=> $session_user,

        'status'=> 0

  ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions for this,

You can create a twig filter:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

you can embed controller in twig:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

you can store a variable in session and access it in twig:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/app_variable.html

you can even create service and register it as a global variable in twig and use it:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services

Comment: Thank you for your very inforvative answer! My question is whether I can use the 1st option without any variables.. I edited my question with the function I d like to use..

Comment: @DimitriosMarkopoulos Well, you can create it as twig function and then call the function in twig template where you need it, or save it to a session and then access it in twig. Why would you want not to use variables? you will have to query for that value every time you change page, why not just save it to session and show it in every page.